# Killing a Windows service programmatically in python

Tags: python, windows, service

I would like to rapidly kill a windows service, rather than stopping it. The service is a python process, so the name of the process is python.exe, and thus I cannot kill the process by name. At the moment, I am using `sc queryex servicename`, then parsing the PID from that and killing by PID. This is problematic for my subprocessing (I am currently shutting down many services at once using `Popen` and `contextlib.exitstack`), as this would require two commands to be run, and thus only one of those commands can be parallelized.

Is it possible to do this in one go? Here is my code:

```
# This portion is not parallel
pid_data = subprocess.check_output(["sc", "queryex", "svcname"])

if pid_data[0] != "PID":
    raise ValueError("Incorrect line number while running svc search.")
else:
    msgsvc_pid = int(pid_data[1])

with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    # This portion is parallel
    stack.enter_context(self._kill_service_by_pid(msgsvc_pid, quiet))
    for svc in svc_list:
        stack.enter_context(self._kill_service(svc, quiet))
```

Where `_kill_service_by_pid` and `_kill_service` are both methods that call `taskkill` to kill a service, either by process name or PID.